# How can I use C++ dlll in C# language?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a problem with Dll in C#. Dll is wrote in C++ language. I want to use structures and methods from dll. I do not know how to write code in C# that i use structures and methods.

C++ code:
this is header.

```
#ifndef _FILTERS_H_
#define _FILTERS_H_

#ifdef __DLL
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

#define _AFXDLL

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <Wingdi.h>
///#include <windows.h>
///#include <afxwin.h>
#include <windef.h>

using namespace std;
///using namespace Gdiplus;
///#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdi32.lib")
///using namespace System;
///using namespace System::Drawing;



#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
#ifndef _RDT_
extern struct __declspec(dllexport) SCIOX_bitmap{
    int width;
    int height;
    int color_depth;
    int* points;
};
#endif
extern __declspec(dllexport) SCIOX_bitmap median(SCIOX_bitmap image, int size);
#else   


#ifndef _RDT_
class __declspec (dllimport) DllClass
{
  public:
    DllClass();
    virtual ~DllClass(void);

  private:

};
#endif


#ifndef _RDT_
#define _RDT_
#endif

#endif /* _FILTERS_H_ */
```

I want call median(attributes); in C# language.

Comment: plenty of examples here in SO, search by this: DllImport

Comment: If you don't know enough about pinvoke to even get started then this is most definitely not the kind of function you want to begin with.  There are very murky memory management problems hidden under the floor mat.  Using C++/CLI is highly recommended.

Comment: Don't use `__declspec(dllexport)` on types.  On plain old data, like `SCIOX_bitmap`, it's useless.  On featureful classes, like `DllClass`, it's harmful.  Get used to exporting global functions that accept the "this" pointer as an explicit argument.  They can call member functions of the object as part of the implementation, but member functions cannot be exported in any way that's even slightly portable.

Comment: Third option - convert the C++ classes to COM Automation-enabled ones and call using COM interop instead of P/Invoke. If you're not familiar with COM, read up on ATL and proceed with caution; COM is hairy on the C++ side.

Comment: search for "PInvoke Interop Assistant"